# TypeError: e is undefined

Tags: jquery

I have created the following function:

```
function validateCampaignSelect(event) {
    var startButton = $jq('[id$=theStart]');
    var campaignSelect = $jq('[id$=campaignSelect]');
    if(campaignSelect.val() == '') {
        if($jq('#campaignErrMsg').length == 0) {
            startButton.after("&nbsp;<span id='campaignErrMsg'>Error: Please select a campaign</span>");
        }
        event.preventDefault();         
    }   
    else {
        $jq("#campaignErrMsg").remove();
    }      
}
```

And here is how I'm calling the method: `onclick="validateCampaignSelect(event); anotherMethodCall();"`

I'm getting the type error: e is undefined.

The code actually works, but I'm seeing the error in firebug.  What am I missing?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply.  I don't mess with JS much.  What code am I missing?

Comment: Where  and How are you using `validateCampaignSelect`?

Comment: What line does the error point to? `e.preventDefault();`?

Comment: I updated the method to the above and no longer get the error, but the prevent default does not work and the form submits.

Comment: @Dman100 you should provide related HTML then. Without _Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example_ it's hard to guess what goes wrong.